# Should I bother with web server database and file encryption?

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-web-services

I'm launching a Python Django web app on Heroku, using the default PostgreSQL database. I'll also be using a AWS S3 to store some files. The client I'm creating the site for is rightly concerned with security and asks is we can encrypt the database and the files stored in S3.

Am I correct in saying the only benefit that encryption will have, is it will protect our data in the unlikely case somebody breaks into one of Amazon's datacenters and happens to steal a hard drive on which our data is located?

I've come to the following conclusions:

- Unless somebody gets hold of my AWS credentials or Heroko login details, the data is as safe as it can be.
- Also, even if the data is encrypted and they get hold of my credentials/login details, they will still be able to read the data.
- The key in keeping the site secure is just making sure nobody gets hold of my credentials/login details.
- It is therefore not necessary to encrypt the database and files unless we believe there is a strong possibility of somebody breaking into an AWS datacenter.

Are my statements above correct?

Comment: If they somehow managed to steal the particular hard drive from the AWS datacentre that had your app on it they'd be able to decrypt the db anyway, since presumably your app needs to be able to do that in order to use the db.

Comment: In that case for what reason would somebody ever encrypt their DB?

Comment: If your client is that worried about someone stealing his HD, then they shouldn't use Heroku or host on AWS. They should buy their own server and host it on their own server cage.

Comment: They are not worried that somebody will steal the HD. They just suggested that we encrypt the DB and I want to tell them that its not necessary. What I basically want to know is if I'm correct in saying this?

Comment: IMHO there is no point encrypting the db itself since if someone can gain access to the db they will be able to access the means to decrypt it again.  More important is access control and use of SSL etc

Comment: people encrypt eg the hard drive on their laptop in case the laptop gets stolen

Comment: That's what I thought. Thanks for all the comments!

Comment: it's similar to why you should not store even encrypted passwords in a db, instead store only a hash - if someone can access the db they likely have your private key too and could decrypt the password, but with a proper use of hash they can't reverse it